Vue & Typescript: Cannot find module or its corresponding type declarations (BUILD ERROR)
This type of question was asked a few times, but here I got the solution and keep getting a build error.
This is my import of Property.ts in my Vue component:
import type { Property } from '@/components/Properties/Property';

First I got a error on the code line: Cannot find module or its corresponding type declarations. So I did everything recommended:
shims-vue.d.ts (just for component imports)
declare module '*.vue';

vite.config.ts
import path from 'path';

resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    },
  },

tsconfig.json
"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    },
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]

Now the error is fixed in my IDE, but as soon as I run a build npm run build I get:
error: Cannot find module '@/components/Properties/Property' or its corresponding type declarations.

24 import type { Property } from '@/components/Properties/Property';

